# What exactly determines what’s in the radiotap header when capturing on WLAN?

Tags: wireshark

I’m doing a study project on wifi signal quality. What I want to do is use Raspberry Pi’s to monitor as many metrics as possible on packet level data. I want to do this by putting wifi adapters on monitor mode (using airmon-ng) and than capture the data about the packets using a wireless network protocol analyzer, like tshark.

What I understand from the wireless networks is that you mainly have three parts: a frame part that has the same information independent of what you’re capturing on, which contains things as frame number, frame length and arrival time. (Want to upload images but don't have 10 reputation yet...).

Then the IEEE 802.11 data which contains the necessary stuff for the network to work. When capturing on WLAN this contains the MAC addresses.

And than we have the radiotap header, which contains all kind of information (signal strength db and dbm, noise level, signal quality, TX value, and much more). This one is a bit different, since this information is actually filled or injected by the wifi adapter you use to capture the data with.

In the present flags you can find which values are actually being injected by the wifi adapter. Now my problem is that for my research I really need as much values as possible. I’ve been working for hours but I didn’t succeed in finding a way to capture with anything more than dmb signal strength (if even available). So this is what I tried so far:

The adapters I used so far are the Edimax EW7811UN, the AirPcap Classic, the AirPcap Tx and two similar alfa adapters with Atheros AR9271 chipset. The AR9271 adapters worked out of the box on raspbian (debian for raspberry pi) on the ath9k_htc driver. Putting them on monitor mode and capturing works fine, but only dbm singal strength is given (as in the screenshots above) in the capture. The Edimax was working out of the box on the 8192cu driver, however it clearly doesn’t support monitor mode. I could put it into monitor mode when booting it on the zd1211rw driver but that didn’t even give the dbm signal strength. Strange thing however, is that a friend tried the exact same Edimax adapter and he could capture, and the only difference we could find is that the lsmod says rtl8192cu and not 8192cu. Strangely, forums are saying that 8192cu is the newer version, however this friend had the newest arch linux kernel installed (newer than the raspbian). So I installed Arch Linux on the pi, but still wasn’t able to put the edimax on 8192cu driver in monitor mode. Then I found a package in the aur repos: dkms-8192cu which was supposed to have a patched version. However, after installing it still didn’t work. Also downloading the driver from the realtek website didn’t work. There is some stuff on patching on the aircrack-ng website, but it actually is mentioning injection of frames and doesn’t really look to be what I exactly need.

Than I bought the Airpcap Classic and the Airpcap Tx to see what they could do. First of all, they have zero linux support so that already is a big drawback since l need to use it from the Pi’s. However even in windows the airpcap’s only capture db and dbm noise and signal quality. It does receive some data at dbm noise level, but it’s worthless since it is always at -100 level. I can boot the Airpcap classic and tx have zd1211B chipset so I can boot them on zd1211rw driver but this also gives no dbm signal value or anything else.

So my question is, what exactly determines what’s in the radiotap header? I guess it would be all in the driver, but I need to be exactly sure before I write off every ath9_htc driver based adapter. I’m about to purchase another adapter which runs on carl9170 driver, however I can’t find no guarantee anywhere that it will give me those values. What I did find in the literature is that the madwifi driver gives (or was giving) noise levels, however it is acquired by Atheros so the project stopped and all websites are suggestion just to use ath9k or ath5k drivers. I tried to install it but I failed because it seems to be really outdate software since the project stopped.

It would be of really big help if someone can explain me what exactly determines what’s inside the radiotap headers, and also if someone could share any experience on when they did capture more than only dbm signal strength values from linux.